# using export in an EnvironmentFile

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

I'm converting an Upstart config file to a systemd unit file. We use lots of environment variables to store magic variables that are imported with the EnvironmentFile directive

> export EC2_URL="https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"

I've found empirically that systemd doesn't like this and that removing the export command makes it less unhappy. But I can't find where in the systemd documentation or elsewhere (the Web), where it says what kind of syntax is allowed in an environment variable file. Does systemd use export implicitly?

Comment: Same problem here. Wanna use the EnvironmentFile in .bashrc as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variable files are not shell scripts.

They are data files, readable by anything that understands a simple `name=value` with `#` for comments syntax.

Don't expect to write them in a shell language.

> I can't find where in the systemd documentation or elsewhere (the Web), where it says what kind of syntax is allowed in an environment variable file.

It's in the `systemd.exec` manual page in the very first paragraph under the `EnvironmentFile=` subheading.